# Is this possible to uninstall one package during another package is installing

Tags: package-management

Is this possible when I installing one package I allow to uninstall another package at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. The package manager exclusively locks its database, therefore only a single package operation can happen at a time. Yes, it is a little inconvenient, but the system is more robust that way.